# Amazon SNS too slow and other issues

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

We are using Amazon SNS to send push notifications to mobile devices. So, just to check how it performs we tested it by creating `100K` random tokens, subscribing them to ten unique and random topics. `10K` s the maximum limit for a topic. 
We wanted to see '100K' delivery failure messages. So, to subscribe the token to the Application for which we want send push messages and to receive the `end_point_arn` and then subscribe this `end_point_arn` to a topic, if we do this for every topic one at a time , it would take maybe more than a day. Is it normal?

So, we tried implementing this paralleling using threads.

Here is my implementation :

```
import redis_wrapper
from AiSns import AiSns
import time
import threading

from datetime import datetime
sns = AiSns(aws_access_key_id='********', aws_secret_access_key='********',region='us-east-1')
redis_sns_push_tokens = redis_wrapper.RedisSNSPushTokens()
redis_sns_apps = redis_wrapper.RedisSNSAPPS()
app_srn = '******'


class subscription_Thread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, push_tokens, app_srn, topic_arn):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.push_tokens = push_tokens
        self.app_srn = app_srn
        self.topic_arn = topic_arn
        aws_secret_access_key='AIjZCIEwWY7bK2g1cI7322VAIvQH1U5Ijdjpbcei',region='us-east-1')
    def run(self):
        subscribe(self.push_tokens, self.app_srn, self.topic_arn)



def subscribe(push_tokens, app_srn, topic_arn):

    for push_token in push_tokens:

        resp_data =  sns.subscribe_user_to_app(app_srn, push_token)
        end_point_arn = resp_data['CreatePlatformEndpointResponse']['CreatePlatformEndpointResult']['EndpointArn']
        subscribe_response = sns.subscribe_user_to_topic(topic_arn, end_point_arn)







tokens = []

test = 'Testing'

for i in range(0, 100000):
    tokens.append(test + '_' + str(i))

unique_topic = 'uniquetopic'
topic = []

for i in range(0, 10):
    topic.append(unique_topic + '_' + str(i))
#topics have been created

topic_arn = []
for a_topic in topic:

    resp_data = sns.create_new_topic(a_topic)
    topic_arn.append(resp_data['CreateTopicResponse']['CreateTopicResult']['TopicArn'])



threads = []
j = 0
for i in range(0, 100000, 1000):
    threads.append(subscription_Thread(tokens[i:i+999], app_srn, topic_arn[j]))
    if i != 0 and i%10000 == 0:
        j += 1

for thread in threads:
     thread.start()


for each_topic_arn in topic_arn:
     send_msg_response = sns.send_message_to_topic(each_topic_arn, 'Done', 'Test', 0)
```

So, we have 10 topics here,  each topic is being subscribed by 10K `end_point_arn`. I run 100 thread. Where each thread subscribes `1K end_point_arn' to a topic.

And after a a couple of hours it threw an exception for each of the hundred thread.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread Thread-99:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "yetAnotherTest.py", line 57, in run
    subscribe(self.push_tokens, self.app_srn, self.topic_arn)
  File "yetAnotherTest.py", line 65, in subscribe
    resp_data =  sns.subscribe_user_to_app(app_srn, push_token)
  File "/home/ubuntu/testing/AiSns.py", line 47, in subscribe_user_to_app
    attributes={'Enabled':enabled}
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/sns/connection.py", line 644, in create_platform_endpoint
    params=params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/sns/connection.py", line 727, in _make_request
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request
None
```

In between it also threw 403 Forbidden , for a few threads.

So, let's say I wanted send push messages to `100K` new user of my app, it will take me around
a day to subscribe and send them? Or is there a way out. Why does this crash occurs?

Comment: Perhaps retry a failed api call a few times. Doesn't sound like it is a high percentage.

Comment: @EricHammond Please explain.

Comment: @extraDarker do you have any more information on your Amazon SNS testing? To your question "let's say I wanted send push messages to 100K new user of my app", don't you need to register them first? IMO registering == write operation is slower than just sending push to them after they're registered (should be read of data on their device_ids/registration_ids)